# Ajax request second parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I'm doing an Ajax request with Vue.js and it has two parameters. The first one is okay, but the second parameters logs undefined in the console. I'm trying to understand how to fix this problem, but i can't find a proper solution.

Here is the $.ajax() code:

```
//$.ajax() to add agregators to users
  addAgregators: function(id1, data1) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(id1);
    console.log(data1);//THIS IS THE PARAMETER RETURNING UNDEFINED
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id1',data1);
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/addAgregators",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            agregators: data1,
            id: id1
        },
        dataType: "json",
        data:formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(obj){
          console.log(obj);//
          this.agr1=obj;
          console.log('success!');
          reDesignAgregators();
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('error');
        }//end error function
    });//end addAgregators $.ajax() function
  },//end addAgregators function
```

I'm supposed to add agregators when I click a button and for this to succeed, i must have a user and an agregator selected, but when I click the button, it gives error and second parameter logs undefined.

and here is the HTML:

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button id="addagr">
                            <img id="add" v-on:click="addAgregators('<?php echo $value1['id'] ;?>')" src="<?php echo $url;?>/public/images/plus.svg">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="col-md-7" id="addlab">Add Agregator</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Hope you guys can help!

Agregators HTML code:

```
<div id="aggs">
                        <?php 
                        if(!empty($agrusr))
                        { 
                            foreach($agrusr as $value1) 
                            {
                                $username= $value1['username'];
                                if($username=="" || $username==NULL)
                                {
                                    $username="Unatributed";
                                }
                                $id='au'.$value1['id'];?>
                                <div class="row oddEven allAggregatores " id='<?php echo $value1['uid'];?>' >
                                    <div id="<?php echo $id;?>">
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value=<?php echo $value1['id'];?>  name="agrwithuser[]" value="2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <span id="items"><?php echo ucfirst($value1['agregator']);?></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="colorsByUsers" :style="{backgroundColor: randomColor()}"><?php echo ucfirst($username);?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php 
                            //  echo "<div id=".$id."><input type='checkbox' name='agrwithuser[]' value=". $value1['id'] .">". $value1['agregator']." &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$username."<br /></div>";                   
                            }
                        }?>

                    </div>
```

Comment: You have added data parameter to times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set `data:formData` which overrides the `data` attribute in the Ajax configuration.

And `formData` contains only the `id1` property which you appended in the line:

```
formData.append('id1',data1);
```

That's why you got only one parameter and the second is `undefined`.

You need to remove the line `data:formData` from your Ajax configuration and call your `addAgregators()` functions with two parameters in your HTML, like this:

```
<img id="add" v-on:click="addAgregators('<?php echo $value1['id'] , $value1['agregators'] ;?>')" src="<?php echo $url;?>/public/images/plus.svg">
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation! But, how should I add the second parameter in the HTML? I confess, i'm new to javascript so i'm also thinking how should I also fix this part.

Comment: It should be `addAgregators('<?php echo $value1['id'] ;?>', '<?php echo $value1['agregators'] ;?>')`.

Comment: vue.js is giving me an error when i apply the missing parameter in the HTML :/

invalid expression: v-on:click="addAgregators('347', '<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: agregators in

Comment: Have you changed `$value1['agregators']` with your own custom variable?
And what if you change it like this: `v-on:click="addAgregators('<?php echo $value1['id'], $value1['agregators'] ;?>')"`??

Comment: the correct way is `v-on:click="addAgregators('<?php echo $value1['id'] ;?>', 'agregators')"` , but there is another problem. I need the value of agregators. agregators are checkboxes and i need that to fully work

Comment: Great, glad it helps.